# How to Load multiple key value pairs as ENV variables into a k8s POD from Azure keyvault secret

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-keyvault

We are using Azure env injector webhook configuration to inject the env variables from azure keyvault into kubernetes pods. we have a bunch of env variables. each variable is created as a secret in azure keyvault. In POD definition env is loaded from specific secret from azure keyvault.

We would like to create all key:values in one azure keyvault and load all of them using a single secret in POD definition.

please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [Flex Volume](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol) to enable integration between your Kubernetes cluster and your Azure Key Vault instance. The way you can achieve this is explained [here](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol/issues/28). In [this article](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol#use-the-keyvault-flexvolume) you have all the steps to perform this integration.